# How do I show that there is an isomorphism between the following two sets?

Tags: group-theory, functions, group-isomorphism

I have the following problem:

> Let $G$ be a group and $H<G$ be a subgroup. Let $E=\{(g,k)\in G\times G: k^{-1}gk\in H\}$ and define two maps $p_1,p_2:E\rightarrow G$ given by $p_1(g,k)=g$, and $p_2(g,k)=k$. I have just shown that $p_2$ is surjective. Now I want to show that for $k\in G$ there is a bijection from $p_2^{-1}(\{k\})$ to the subgroup $kHk^{-1}$.

I know that I could find a function between these two sets and show that this function is bijective and also a morphism, but I thought if it also works as follows:

By definition $$p_2^{-1}(\{k\})=\{(g,k)\in G\times G:k^{-1}gk\in H\}=\{g\in G:k^{-1}gk\in H\}=\{g\in G:g\in kHk^{-1}\}=kHk^{-1}$$
Now I thought that we have immediately show that these sets are bijective, since they are equal, but I'm not sure if this works.

Could someone take a look at my solution?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You write $\{(g,k)\in G\times G:k^{-1}gk\in H\}=\{g\in G:k^{-1}gk\in H\}$, but the first set is a subset of $G \times G$ while the second is a subset of $G$. So they cannot be equal as sets (provided they are both non-empty); you need to map between them somehow.

Comment: but somehow $k$ in the first set isn't really necessairly so I could also skip the first set, couldn't I?

Comment: $p_2^{-1}(\{k\}) \subseteq E \subseteq G \times G$, so you'll have to map from $G \times G \to G$ at some point. I agree that $g$ is the important information here - you need to extract that. Can you see a map that does that?

Comment: so since $p_2^{-1}(\{k\})=\{(g,k):g\in kHk^{-1}\}$ I think that we could take $\phi(g,k)=g$?

Comment: Yes, although you have already given this map in your post as $p_1$.

Comment: ah perfect thanks!

Comment: sorry can I ask again something, to check that this map is well defined, what do I need to show? because I always don't know what exaclty I need to show for well-defindness